# Adapt existing GOST code in C to hash a file

Tags: c, algorithm, hash, cryptography

I am trying to hand-code the GOST hash function using C. I came across the following code by Markku-Juhani Saarinen (from [link](http://www.autochthonous.org/crypto/gosthash.tar.gz)).

```
/*
 *  gosthash.c 
 *  21 Apr 1998  Markku-Juhani Saarinen <mjos@ssh.fi>
 * 
 *  GOST R 34.11-94, Russian Standard Hash Function
 *
 *  Copyright (c) 1998 SSH Communications Security, Finland
 *  All rights reserved.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "gosthash.h"

/* lookup tables : each of these has two rotated 4-bit S-Boxes */

unsigned long gost_sbox_1[256];
unsigned long gost_sbox_2[256];
unsigned long gost_sbox_3[256];
unsigned long gost_sbox_4[256];

/* initialize the lookup tables */

void gosthash_init()
{
  int a, b, i;
  unsigned long ax, bx, cx, dx;

  /* 4-bit S-Boxes */ 

  unsigned long sbox[8][16] =
    {
    {  4, 10,  9,  2, 13,  8,  0, 14,  6, 11,  1, 12,  7, 15,  5,  3 },
    { 14, 11,  4, 12,  6, 13, 15, 10,  2,  3,  8,  1,  0,  7,  5,  9 },
    {  5,  8,  1, 13, 10,  3,  4,  2, 14, 15, 12,  7,  6,  0,  9, 11 },
    {  7, 13, 10,  1,  0,  8,  9, 15, 14,  4,  6, 12, 11,  2,  5,  3 },
    {  6, 12,  7,  1,  5, 15, 13,  8,  4, 10,  9, 14,  0,  3, 11,  2 },
    {  4, 11, 10,  0,  7,  2,  1, 13,  3,  6,  8,  5,  9, 12, 15, 14 },
    { 13, 11,  4,  1,  3, 15,  5,  9,  0, 10, 14,  7,  6,  8,  2, 12 },
    {  1, 15, 13,  0,  5,  7, 10,  4,  9,  2,  3, 14,  6, 11,  8, 12 }  
    };

  /* s-box precomputation */

  i = 0;
  for (a = 0; a < 16; a++)
    {
      ax = sbox[1][a] << 15;      
      bx = sbox[3][a] << 23;
      cx = sbox[5][a];        
      cx = (cx >> 1) | (cx << 31);
      dx = sbox[7][a] << 7;

      for (b = 0; b < 16; b++)
    {
      gost_sbox_1[i] = ax | (sbox[0][b] << 11);       
      gost_sbox_2[i] = bx | (sbox[2][b] << 19);
      gost_sbox_3[i] = cx | (sbox[4][b] << 27);   
      gost_sbox_4[i++] = dx | (sbox[6][b] << 3);
    }
    }
}

/*
 *  A macro that performs a full encryption round of GOST 28147-89.
 *  Temporary variable t assumed and variables r and l for left and right
 *  blocks
 */ 

#define GOST_ENCRYPT_ROUND(k1, k2) \
t = (k1) + r; \
l ^= gost_sbox_1[t & 0xff] ^ gost_sbox_2[(t >> 8) & 0xff] ^ \
gost_sbox_3[(t >> 16) & 0xff] ^ gost_sbox_4[t >> 24]; \
t = (k2) + l; \
r ^= gost_sbox_1[t & 0xff] ^ gost_sbox_2[(t >> 8) & 0xff] ^ \
gost_sbox_3[(t >> 16) & 0xff] ^ gost_sbox_4[t >> 24]; \

/* encrypt a block with the given key */

#define GOST_ENCRYPT(key) \
GOST_ENCRYPT_ROUND(key[0], key[1]) \
GOST_ENCRYPT_ROUND(key[2], key[3]) \
GOST_ENCRYPT_ROUND(key[4], key[5]) \
GOST_ENCRYPT_ROUND(key[6], key[7]) \
GOST_ENCRYPT_ROUND(key[0], key[1]) \
GOST_ENCRYPT_ROUND(key[2], key[3]) \
GOST_ENCRYPT_ROUND(key[4], key[5]) \
GOST_ENCRYPT_ROUND(key[6], key[7]) \
GOST_ENCRYPT_ROUND(key[0], key[1]) \
GOST_ENCRYPT_ROUND(key[2], key[3]) \
GOST_ENCRYPT_ROUND(key[4], key[5]) \
GOST_ENCRYPT_ROUND(key[6], key[7]) \
GOST_ENCRYPT_ROUND(key[7], key[6]) \
GOST_ENCRYPT_ROUND(key[5], key[4]) \
GOST_ENCRYPT_ROUND(key[3], key[2]) \
GOST_ENCRYPT_ROUND(key[1], key[0]) \
t = r; \
r = l; \
l = t;

/* 
 *  "chi" compression function. the result is stored over h
 */

void gosthash_compress(unsigned long *h, unsigned long *m)
{
  int i;
  unsigned long l, r, t, key[8], u[8], v[8], w[8], s[8];

  memcpy(u, h, sizeof(u));
  memcpy(v, m, sizeof(u));

  for (i = 0; i < 8; i += 2)
    {        
      w[0] = u[0] ^ v[0];          /* w = u xor v */
      w[1] = u[1] ^ v[1];
      w[2] = u[2] ^ v[2];
      w[3] = u[3] ^ v[3];
      w[4] = u[4] ^ v[4];
      w[5] = u[5] ^ v[5];
      w[6] = u[6] ^ v[6];
      w[7] = u[7] ^ v[7];      

      /* P-Transformation */

      key[0] = (w[0]  & 0x000000ff) | ((w[2] & 0x000000ff) << 8) |
    ((w[4] & 0x000000ff) << 16) | ((w[6] & 0x000000ff) << 24);
      key[1] = ((w[0] & 0x0000ff00) >> 8)  | (w[2]  & 0x0000ff00) |
    ((w[4] & 0x0000ff00) << 8) | ((w[6] & 0x0000ff00) << 16);
      key[2] = ((w[0] & 0x00ff0000) >> 16) | ((w[2] & 0x00ff0000) >> 8) |
    (w[4] & 0x00ff0000) | ((w[6] & 0x00ff0000) << 8);
      key[3] = ((w[0] & 0xff000000) >> 24) | ((w[2] & 0xff000000) >> 16) |
    ((w[4] & 0xff000000) >> 8) | (w[6] & 0xff000000);  
      key[4] = (w[1] & 0x000000ff) | ((w[3] & 0x000000ff) << 8) |
    ((w[5] & 0x000000ff) << 16) | ((w[7] & 0x000000ff) << 24);
      key[5] = ((w[1] & 0x0000ff00) >> 8) | (w[3]  & 0x0000ff00) |
    ((w[5] & 0x0000ff00) << 8) | ((w[7] & 0x0000ff00) << 16);
      key[6] = ((w[1] & 0x00ff0000) >> 16) | ((w[3] & 0x00ff0000) >> 8) |
    (w[5] & 0x00ff0000) | ((w[7] & 0x00ff0000) << 8);
      key[7] = ((w[1] & 0xff000000) >> 24) | ((w[3] & 0xff000000) >> 16) |
    ((w[5] & 0xff000000) >> 8) | (w[7] & 0xff000000);  

      r = h[i];                /* encriphering transformation */
      l = h[i + 1];      
      GOST_ENCRYPT(key);

      s[i] = r;
      s[i + 1] = l;

      if (i == 6)
    break;

      l = u[0] ^ u[2];             /* U = A(U) */
      r = u[1] ^ u[3];
      u[0] = u[2];
      u[1] = u[3];
      u[2] = u[4];
      u[3] = u[5];
      u[4] = u[6];
      u[5] = u[7];
      u[6] = l;
      u[7] = r;

      if (i == 2)              /* Constant C_3 */
    {
      u[0] ^= 0xff00ff00; 
      u[1] ^= 0xff00ff00; 
      u[2] ^= 0x00ff00ff;
      u[3] ^= 0x00ff00ff;
      u[4] ^= 0x00ffff00;
      u[5] ^= 0xff0000ff;
      u[6] ^= 0x000000ff;
      u[7] ^= 0xff00ffff;       
    }

      l = v[0];                /* V = A(A(V)) */
      r = v[2];
      v[0] = v[4];
      v[2] = v[6];
      v[4] = l ^ r;
      v[6] = v[0] ^ r;
      l = v[1];
      r = v[3];
      v[1] = v[5];
      v[3] = v[7];
      v[5] = l ^ r;
      v[7] = v[1] ^ r;
    }

  /* 12 rounds of the LFSR (computed from a product matrix) and xor in M */

  u[0] = m[0] ^ s[6];
  u[1] = m[1] ^ s[7];
  u[2] = m[2] ^ (s[0] << 16) ^ (s[0] >> 16) ^ (s[0] & 0xffff) ^ 
    (s[1] & 0xffff) ^ (s[1] >> 16) ^ (s[2] << 16) ^ s[6] ^ (s[6] << 16) ^
    (s[7] & 0xffff0000) ^ (s[7] >> 16);
  u[3] = m[3] ^ (s[0] & 0xffff) ^ (s[0] << 16) ^ (s[1] & 0xffff) ^ 
    (s[1] << 16) ^ (s[1] >> 16) ^ (s[2] << 16) ^ (s[2] >> 16) ^
    (s[3] << 16) ^ s[6] ^ (s[6] << 16) ^ (s[6] >> 16) ^ (s[7] & 0xffff) ^ 
    (s[7] << 16) ^ (s[7] >> 16);
  u[4] = m[4] ^ 
    (s[0] & 0xffff0000) ^ (s[0] << 16) ^ (s[0] >> 16) ^ 
    (s[1] & 0xffff0000) ^ (s[1] >> 16) ^ (s[2] << 16) ^ (s[2] >> 16) ^
    (s[3] << 16) ^ (s[3] >> 16) ^ (s[4] << 16) ^ (s[6] << 16) ^ 
    (s[6] >> 16) ^(s[7] & 0xffff) ^ (s[7] << 16) ^ (s[7] >> 16);
  u[5] = m[5] ^ (s[0] << 16) ^ (s[0] >> 16) ^ (s[0] & 0xffff0000) ^
    (s[1] & 0xffff) ^ s[2] ^ (s[2] >> 16) ^ (s[3] << 16) ^ (s[3] >> 16) ^
    (s[4] << 16) ^ (s[4] >> 16) ^ (s[5] << 16) ^  (s[6] << 16) ^ 
    (s[6] >> 16) ^ (s[7] & 0xffff0000) ^ (s[7] << 16) ^ (s[7] >> 16);
  u[6] = m[6] ^ s[0] ^ (s[1] >> 16) ^ (s[2] << 16) ^ s[3] ^ (s[3] >> 16) ^
    (s[4] << 16) ^ (s[4] >> 16) ^ (s[5] << 16) ^ (s[5] >> 16) ^ s[6] ^ 
    (s[6] << 16) ^ (s[6] >> 16) ^ (s[7] << 16);
  u[7] = m[7] ^ (s[0] & 0xffff0000) ^ (s[0] << 16) ^ (s[1] & 0xffff) ^ 
    (s[1] << 16) ^ (s[2] >> 16) ^ (s[3] << 16) ^ s[4] ^ (s[4] >> 16) ^
    (s[5] << 16) ^ (s[5] >> 16) ^ (s[6] >> 16) ^ (s[7] & 0xffff) ^ 
    (s[7] << 16) ^ (s[7] >> 16);

  /* 16 * 1 round of the LFSR and xor in H */

  v[0] = h[0] ^ (u[1] << 16) ^ (u[0] >> 16);
  v[1] = h[1] ^ (u[2] << 16) ^ (u[1] >> 16);
  v[2] = h[2] ^ (u[3] << 16) ^ (u[2] >> 16);
  v[3] = h[3] ^ (u[4] << 16) ^ (u[3] >> 16);
  v[4] = h[4] ^ (u[5] << 16) ^ (u[4] >> 16);
  v[5] = h[5] ^ (u[6] << 16) ^ (u[5] >> 16);
  v[6] = h[6] ^ (u[7] << 16) ^ (u[6] >> 16);
  v[7] = h[7] ^ (u[0] & 0xffff0000) ^ (u[0] << 16) ^ (u[7] >> 16) ^
    (u[1] & 0xffff0000) ^ (u[1] << 16) ^ (u[6] << 16) ^ (u[7] & 0xffff0000);

  /* 61 rounds of LFSR, mixing up h (computed from a product matrix) */

  h[0] = (v[0] & 0xffff0000) ^ (v[0] << 16) ^ (v[0] >> 16) ^ (v[1] >> 16) ^ 
    (v[1] & 0xffff0000) ^ (v[2] << 16) ^ (v[3] >> 16) ^ (v[4] << 16) ^
    (v[5] >> 16) ^ v[5] ^ (v[6] >> 16) ^ (v[7] << 16) ^ (v[7] >> 16) ^ 
    (v[7] & 0xffff);
  h[1] = (v[0] << 16) ^ (v[0] >> 16) ^ (v[0] & 0xffff0000) ^ (v[1] & 0xffff) ^ 
    v[2] ^ (v[2] >> 16) ^ (v[3] << 16) ^ (v[4] >> 16) ^ (v[5] << 16) ^ 
    (v[6] << 16) ^ v[6] ^ (v[7] & 0xffff0000) ^ (v[7] >> 16);
  h[2] = (v[0] & 0xffff) ^ (v[0] << 16) ^ (v[1] << 16) ^ (v[1] >> 16) ^ 
    (v[1] & 0xffff0000) ^ (v[2] << 16) ^ (v[3] >> 16) ^ v[3] ^ (v[4] << 16) ^
    (v[5] >> 16) ^ v[6] ^ (v[6] >> 16) ^ (v[7] & 0xffff) ^ (v[7] << 16) ^
    (v[7] >> 16);
  h[3] = (v[0] << 16) ^ (v[0] >> 16) ^ (v[0] & 0xffff0000) ^ 
    (v[1] & 0xffff0000) ^ (v[1] >> 16) ^ (v[2] << 16) ^ (v[2] >> 16) ^ v[2] ^ 
    (v[3] << 16) ^ (v[4] >> 16) ^ v[4] ^ (v[5] << 16) ^ (v[6] << 16) ^ 
    (v[7] & 0xffff) ^ (v[7] >> 16);
  h[4] = (v[0] >> 16) ^ (v[1] << 16) ^ v[1] ^ (v[2] >> 16) ^ v[2] ^ 
    (v[3] << 16) ^ (v[3] >> 16) ^ v[3] ^ (v[4] << 16) ^ (v[5] >> 16) ^ 
    v[5] ^ (v[6] << 16) ^ (v[6] >> 16) ^ (v[7] << 16);
  h[5] = (v[0] << 16) ^ (v[0] & 0xffff0000) ^ (v[1] << 16) ^ (v[1] >> 16) ^ 
    (v[1] & 0xffff0000) ^ (v[2] << 16) ^ v[2] ^ (v[3] >> 16) ^ v[3] ^ 
    (v[4] << 16) ^ (v[4] >> 16) ^ v[4] ^ (v[5] << 16) ^ (v[6] << 16) ^
    (v[6] >> 16) ^ v[6] ^ (v[7] << 16) ^ (v[7] >> 16) ^ (v[7] & 0xffff0000);
  h[6] = v[0] ^ v[2] ^ (v[2] >> 16) ^ v[3] ^ (v[3] << 16) ^ v[4] ^ 
    (v[4] >> 16) ^ (v[5] << 16) ^ (v[5] >> 16) ^ v[5] ^ (v[6] << 16) ^ 
    (v[6] >> 16) ^ v[6] ^ (v[7] << 16) ^ v[7];
  h[7] = v[0] ^ (v[0] >> 16) ^ (v[1] << 16) ^ (v[1] >> 16) ^ (v[2] << 16) ^
    (v[3] >> 16) ^ v[3] ^ (v[4] << 16) ^ v[4] ^ (v[5] >> 16) ^ v[5] ^
    (v[6] << 16) ^ (v[6] >> 16) ^ (v[7] << 16) ^ v[7];
}

/* Clear the state of the given context structure. */

void gosthash_reset(GostHashCtx *ctx)
{
  memset(ctx->sum, 0, 32);
  memset(ctx->hash, 0, 32);
  memset(ctx->len, 0, 32);
  memset(ctx->partial, 0, 32);
  ctx->partial_bytes = 0;  
}

/* Mix in a 32-byte chunk ("stage 3") */

void gosthash_bytes(GostHashCtx *ctx, const unsigned char *buf, size_t bits)
{
  int i, j;
  unsigned long a, b, c, m[8];

  /* convert bytes to a long words and compute the sum */

  j = 0;
  c = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
      a = ((unsigned long) buf[j]) | 
    (((unsigned long) buf[j + 1]) << 8) | 
    (((unsigned long) buf[j + 2]) << 16) | 
    (((unsigned long) buf[j + 3]) << 24);
      j += 4;
      m[i] = a;
      b = ctx->sum[i];
      c = a + c + ctx->sum[i];
      ctx->sum[i] = c;
      c = ((c < a) || (c < b)) ? 1 : 0;     
    }

  /* compress */

  gosthash_compress(ctx->hash, m);

  /* a 64-bit counter should be sufficient */

  ctx->len[0] += bits;
  if (ctx->len[0] < bits)
    ctx->len[1]++;  
}

/* Mix in len bytes of data for the given buffer. */

void gosthash_update(GostHashCtx *ctx, const unsigned char *buf, size_t len)
{
  size_t i, j;

  i = ctx->partial_bytes;
  j = 0;
  while (i < 32 && j < len)
    ctx->partial[i++] = buf[j++];

  if (i < 32)
    {
      ctx->partial_bytes = i;
      return;
    }  
  gosthash_bytes(ctx, ctx->partial, 256);

  while ((j + 32) < len)
    {
      gosthash_bytes(ctx, &buf[j], 256);
      j += 32;
    }

  i = 0;
  while (j < len)
    ctx->partial[i++] = buf[j++];
  ctx->partial_bytes = i;
}


/* Compute and save the 32-byte digest. */

void gosthash_final(GostHashCtx *ctx, unsigned char *digest)
{
  int i, j;
  unsigned long a;

  /* adjust and mix in the last chunk */

  if (ctx->partial_bytes > 0)
    {
      memset(&ctx->partial[ctx->partial_bytes], 0, 32 - ctx->partial_bytes);
      gosthash_bytes(ctx, ctx->partial, ctx->partial_bytes << 3);      
    }

  /* mix in the length and the sum */

  gosthash_compress(ctx->hash, ctx->len);  
  gosthash_compress(ctx->hash, ctx->sum);  

  /* convert the output to bytes */

  j = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
      a = ctx->hash[i];
      digest[j] = (unsigned char) a;
      digest[j + 1] = (unsigned char) (a >> 8);
      digest[j + 2] = (unsigned char) (a >> 16);
      digest[j + 3] = (unsigned char) (a >> 24);    
      j += 4;
    }  
}
```

However, there is no **main()** function which I can use to compile an executable. I wanted a main of the type `main(int argc, char *argv[])` with which to call a file with the produced executable and have the file's contents hashed.

I have gone through the code over and over again but I am stuck with calling the code's functions, I don't know how to proceed. Please, any ideas on how I can fill my main function to run this code?

**EDIT**

I tried the following `main()` code but it does not seem to work:

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if (argc!=2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Provide name of one source file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *clear_file = argv[1];
    const char *FILENAME_IN = clear_file;

    FILE *infile;
    infile = fopen(FILENAME_IN, "r");

    GostHashCtx *ctx = malloc(sizeof(GostHashCtx));
    unsigned char *digest, *buf;
    char c;

    if(infile == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Source file not found.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    gosthash_init();
    gosthash_reset(ctx); //printf("CTX.PB=%d\n\n",ctx->partial_bytes);

    int quit = 0;
    while (quit == 0) {
        int p = 0;
        buf = malloc(256);
        strcpy(buf, "");
        while(((c = fgetc(infile)) != EOF) && (p < 256)) {
            *(buf+p) = c;
            p++;
        }

        //*(buf+p) = '\0';
        if(c == EOF) quit = 1;

        gosthash_update(ctx, buf, 256);
        free(buf);
    }

    digest = malloc(256); 
    strcpy(digest, "");

    gosthash_final(ctx, digest);

    printf("%s\n", digest);

    free(ctx);
    free(digest);
}
```

To verify the output, I used an online tool to quickly convert the resulting string `digest` to HEX but the result is incorrect for known test values of GOST hashing.
Please, any ideas as to why this might be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so first you have to call `gosthash_init` to fill the lookup tables. Then you allocate as many contexts of type `GostHashCtx` that you require - you probably just need one in your case. You can reset it in advance to make sure the context is filled with zero values.

Now you call `gosthash_update` one or multiple times to hash all the bytes in the file (sequentially, of course). Finally you call `gosthash_final` to create the hash. These steps perform the actual hashing.

If you want to hash something else, first call `gosthash_reset`, and then `gosthash_update` and `gosthash_final` again.

Comment: Thanks for that answer @MaartenBodewes. I will try to do it that way and see if it works. I have a couple of questions though: first, how do I determine the number of `GostHashCtx` contexts I'll need. Then, shouldn't I make the context (`GostHashCtx`) and the `digest` from `gosthash_final` global variables to enable me to use their values from function to function?

Comment: You should never make anything global unless strictly required. It's probably easiest to simply create a new context (allocated `GostHashCtx`) each time you require a hash to be calculated. You can reuse a context after you've calculated a hash (by using the reset functionality), but it will only give you minimal performance / memory benefits. The context is just required to store the intermediate hash state in between the calls of update and final.

Comment: Thanks very much Maarten. Using your advice I succeeded to obtain a digest to show off. However, the result contained in the string `unsigned char *digest` when converted to HEX is incorrect for test inputs with known with known GOST hash values. I have edited the question above to show my code. I don't know whether I made any mistakes in implementing.

Comment: Chris is right, you should not update the hash using a static number of bytes. You should always check how many bytes are actually read into the buffer and then update with that amount of bytes. This is probably an implementation mistake, not an issue with the type or given order of calls.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I corrected the mistake using read() as Chris suggested, however I strangely am unable to hash beyond the first byte in the file.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction with the order of calls. The rest of my problems were just implementation issues. I have everything sorted out now. My GOST hash code now works like a charm. Thank you so very much indeed @MaartenBodewes.

Answer (score 0):

When you get to the end of the file, if the file length is not a multiple of 256, you won't fill the buffer, but you still call `gosthash_update` with a size of 256, which means it will hash in whatever random garbage happens to be in the rest of the buffer.  Try changing that to `gosthash_update(ctx, buf, p);`

There's also no need to call `malloc` -- just use local vars.  You can simplify things even more by using open/read instead of fopen/fgetc:

```
char buf[2048];  /* or any size you like */
int len;
int fd = open(FILENAME_IN, O_RDONLY);
GostHashCtxt ctx;
gosthash_init();
gosthash_reset(&ctx);
while ((len = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf)) > 0)
    gosthash_update(&ctx, buf, len);
gosthash_final(&ctx, buf);
write(1, buf, 32);
```

Note that the resulting digest is *NOT* a null-terminated string -- it is 32 bytes of binary data.  So you can't safely print it with `printf("%s",`

Comment: Thanks very much @ChrisDodd. I corrected my code to use `while ((len = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf)) > 0)) gosthash_update(ctx, buf, len);` instead to read the file's contents. Normally this is supposed to read through the whole file but strangely I get a correct hash only for the first character in the file. Anything beyond the first character does not get hashed, so the hash result is always the hash of the first character in the file, almost as if only the first character is read. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @ChrisDodd. I corrected it using `size_t nread;` and `while ((nread = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), infile)) > 0) gosthash_update(ctx, buf, nread);` instead. I'm good now!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has the same problem I had, I am posting my final code for the `main()` function here. Thanks again to @ChrisDodd and @MaartenBodewes for their help.

**EDIT:** I have made it CW for any improvements. (The current code works fine under Windows with *MinGW* but does ***Segmentation fault*** in certain environments like openSUSE Linux due to the instruction `gosthash_final(ctx, digest);` which I traced back to the call to `gosthash_compress()` in the `gosthash_final()` function.)

```
/* I used this function to get the hash result in HEX format */
void hexify(unsigned char *in, char *out) {
    char hex[64], tmp[3];
    int i; 
    hex[0]='\0';
    for(i=0; i<32; i++ )
    {
        sprintf(tmp, "%02X", in[i]);
        strcat(hex, tmp); 
    }
    strcpy(out, hex);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if (argc!=2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Provide name of one source file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char *clear_file = argv[1];
    const char *FILENAME_IN = clear_file;

    FILE *infile;
    infile = fopen(FILENAME_IN, "r");

    GostHashCtx *ctx = malloc(sizeof(GostHashCtx));
    unsigned char digest[32], buf[16];

    char hex[64];
    hex[0]='\0';

    if(infile == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Source file not found.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    gosthash_init();
    gosthash_reset(ctx); 

    size_t nread;
    while ((nread = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), infile)) > 0)
        gosthash_update(ctx, buf, nread);
    fclose(infile);

    digest[0]='\0';
    gosthash_final(ctx, digest);

    hexify(digest, hex); 

    printf("HASH= %s\n", hex);

    free(ctx);
    return 0;
}
```